# How can I get Eclipse work with Maven and SVN correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a multi-modules Maven project checked out from SVN. I installed m2eclipse in Eclipse. Then I imported the project into Eclipse. Everything is fine. But after I update my Maven project from SVN(outside of Eclipse), Eclipse will give me a lot of errors and warnings unless I import the project again. That is really annoying. I have to import the project every time that I update it from SVN.

Is there a solution?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Do you have the eclipse project files stored under Subversion too?

Comment: If you mean the file .project, the answer is no. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) see here: http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Then install, [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) and *m2eclipse extras* as mentioned here: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html

After, these are done.

1. Open Eclipse go to `Window > Open Perspective > Other... > SVN Repository Exploring`
2. Add URL to SVN repository/code base.
3. Select a project. Right Click and select `Checkout as Maven Project`. You're done.

Now, update, commit, delete, build all from inside Eclipse.

Comment: For anyone finding the sonatype.org links dead, the project has moved to http://eclipse.org/m2e/.

Answer (score 3):

Install m2e and subclipse from the [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) depending on what version of Eclipse you have. Then:

1. Open Eclipse go to `Window > Open Perspective > Other... > SVN Repository Exploring`.
2. Add your svn url to SVN repository/code base.
3. Select a project. Right Click and select `Checkout`.
4. Assuming your project has a pom.xml, switch back to your Java perspective, select the project that was just imported, right click and select `Configure > Convert to Maven Project`.

Answer (score 0):

try the other plugin of maven may be more stable.
http://www.eclipse.org/iam/

Svn have a very stable plugin

But frankly it's not working good think about switching to intellij if you work with maven the integration between the IDE and maven is really working period

may be the free version of intellij is enough for your needs